# How to send data securely in a ajax call to a controller method so that its not exploitable by looking at the developer tools

Tags: javascript, ajax, ssl, https, google-developers-console

I have a requirement where I have to securely send sensitive data like database connection strings in a ajax call. If I encrypt it , then the code used to encrypt will also be available in the front end which makes it exploitable again.
We have checks in backend to validate requests but the issue here is , the data sent in the ajax call should not be available or atleast not in a readable form.
Any suggestions on how can I do it?

Comment: Not available or readable *to whom*?  If a third party, that's what HTTPS is for.  If the current user, then take a step back and examine the actual goal here, because you're asking the client to provide information that you don't want the client to have.

Comment: Alright I want for third party and how can I use Https for that ? What all i must change, I mean I use a c# controller action which is called from ajax. So how do i bring in https. I am not quite aware of this concept

Comment: That's fairly broad, and a Google search for "asp.net mvc ssl" finds a lot of helpful information.

Answer (score 0):

If you ajax on client side, it is not possible. You can look into server side rendering.